# A conflicted love letter

Tags: riddle

> Hello again.
>
> You're looking more radiant than ever. Not for long.
>
> You simply get hotter with age!
>   Though, I'm not fond of your new piercing...
>
> Did you lose some weight? Probably for the best.
>
> I hope to see you again. With mixed emotions.
>
> BB

Your tasks are to work out the:

- author
- subject
- meaning of each line

Hint:

> The second B in 'BB' stands for 'boy', but other than the last line the gender of the author is not important.

Hint #2:

> What gets hotter and more radiant with age. And new piercings...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are a

> birthday cake

You're looking more radiant than ever. Not for long.

> You have more candles alight, however I will soon blow them out.

You simply get hotter with age! Though, I'm not fond of your new piercing...

> More candles create more heat, not fond of the number of these as this is your age increasing.

Did you lose some weight? Probably for the best.

> Maybe now you and friends have eaten some.

I hope to see you again. With mixed emotions.

> Look forward to your next birthday, but as you get older may not so much.

Author - BB

> Birthday Boy

Comment: rybo111 - that's a very sweet riddle, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well it is

> Sun (or any dying star)

You're looking more radiant than ever. Not for long.

> Dying stars look more bright (or emit more light) for a short duration

You simply get hotter with age! Though, I'm not fond of your new piercing...

> Sun / any star getting converted to a giant/dwarf as time passes and they may turn into black hole ?!

Did you lose some weight? Probably for the best.

> Dying star loses mass and hence weight too

I hope to see you again. With mixed emotions.

> A dying star can reborn (to be seen again) which is both good and bad.

BB

> A Beginner/Bachelor (in Astronomy related branch of Physics that starts with 'B') in B____.

So, the author is

> An astronomy enthusiast

Subject is

> Aging sun/ star

Comment: Nope, but a good guess

Comment: Damn! I enjoyed how you solved my puzzle so fast so I found this in your answered questions and your answer was what came to my mind when I read it and I saw the first answer and I was sure I'm gonna be the only one but you nailed me! tho I didn't have any idea for the BB part. But I have another idea about the piercing part which I'll post as an answer forking yours:D

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something like

> a grenade?

*A conflicted love letter*

> Grenades are involved in *conflict*, for sure.

*You're looking more radiant than ever. Not for long.*

> A grenade is radiant when it explodes, but the explosion doesn't last long.

*You simply get hotter with age! Though, I'm not fond of your new piercing...*

> Heat must also be involved in the explosion, and the 'piercing' is of course the pin of the grenade.

*Did you lose some weight? Probably for the best.*

> After it's exploded, it doesn't really weigh anything any more - it's all gone.

*I hope to see you again. With mixed emotions.*

> I bet you would have mixed emotions if you were hoping to see a grenade again!

*BB*

> Apparently there's something called a BB grenade?

Comment: That's not the answer, sorry

Comment: @rybo111 I had another idea, which I couldn't make fit all the lines ... it's not anything to do with a particular fantasy novel, by any chance?

Comment: it's not, but I'd like to see it :)